# How to retrieve data from Database in Android SQLite?

Tags: java, android

I would like to query the data from "**names**" how can I do it?
I try but it seems that I only have to consult through the primary key, I am totally new in java and I am starting, I don't know what is the method to search through "nombres" (names in english)

```
public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos) {
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL("CREATE TABLE personajes (codigo text primary key, nombres text, contraseña text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

When I register with a number in "**codigo**" and then consult it returns the data correctly, but when I register with text example: "`asdasd`" the console returns: `E / SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: asdasd`

Query method:

```
    private EditText et_codigo, et_nombres, et_contraseña;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregarpersonaje);


et_codigo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_codigo);
et_nombres = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_nombres);
et_contraseña = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_contraseña);

}



    public void Buscar(View view){
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatabase = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    String codigo = et_codigo.getText().toString();


    if(!codigo.isEmpty()){
        Cursor fila = BaseDeDatabase.rawQuery
                ("select nombres, contraseña from personajes where codigo =" + codigo, null);



        if(fila.moveToFirst()){
            et_nombres.setText(fila.getString(0));
            et_contraseña.setText(fila.getString(1));
            BaseDeDatabase.close();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"No existe el artículo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            BaseDeDatabase.close();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debes introducir el código del artículo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're in need of a [SQL tutorial](http://www.sqlcourse.com/). Stack Overflow is not a good place to look for this type of fundamental information, particularly given the fact that what you need cannot be covered in the space of a few paragraphs. There are plenty of sites and books that cover the material you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Room database. It provides an abstraction layer over SQLite, and it is easier to use.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: i cant understand that, dont have any solution for my method?